# Use react hook in HOC with passed params

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hoc

I am trying to create HOC and use custom react hook inside. Also in order to use hook I need to pass paras to HOC, but I get error for use hook only in function body. My HOC is:

```
export const withUseAxisTranslate = (props) => {
  const [t] = useAxisTranslate(props.namespace);
  return (WrappedComponent) => (moreProps) => <WrappedComponent {...moreProps} t={t} />;
};
```

My useAxisTranslate looks like:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

//This one is behave like regular i18 translate
//It returns like t() in array function and use axis name in order to find specific key by axis name
const useAxisTranslate = (namespace) => {
  return [
    (stringToTranslate) => {
      const axisName = useSelector((state) => state.axisConfig.axis.name.toLowerCase());
      const [t] = useTranslation(namespace);
      return t(`${axisName}.${stringToTranslate}`);
    },
  ];
};

export default useAxisTranslate;
```

My call to it is:

```
compose(
  withWidth(),
  withUseAxisTranslate({ namespace: 'header' }),
)(MyComponent);
```

The error I got is:

[image]

I have no idea why I get this error since I do not use classes here
Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to note here

- You are trying to use `useAxisTranslate` which is meant to be a custom hook within `withUseAxisTranslate` which is not component but a function returning another function.
- You are using `useSelector` and `useTranslation` in the custom hook inside of the the returned function which again violates the rules

The solution here is to correct both the things like below

```
export const withUseAxisTranslate = (props) => {
  return (WrappedComponent) => (moreProps) => {
        const [t] = useAxisTranslate(props.namespace);
        return <WrappedComponent {...moreProps} t={t} />
  }
};
```

and useAxisTranslate as

```
const useAxisTranslate = (namespace) => {
  const axisName = useSelector((state) => state.axisConfig.axis.name.toLowerCase());
  const [t] = useTranslation(namespace);
  const translateFunction = (stringToTranslate) => {
      return t(`${axisName}.${stringToTranslate}`);
  };
  return [
    translateFunction
  ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `useAxisTranslate` hook inside the body of the component, like so

```
export const withUseAxisTranslate = (props) => {
    return (WrappedComponent) => (moreProps) => {
        const [t] = useAxisTranslate(props.namespace);
        return <WrappedComponent {...moreProps} t={t} />;
    }
};
```